# Zoom client crashes on Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS

Tags: crash, zoom-meeting

a quick help. I just installed Ubuntu Studio 22.04 and for some strange reason Zoom client crashes on start. Not sure if it's just me or if this is a common problem across. I installed zoom client downloaded from their official website (https://zoom.us/download#client_4meeting). After installing when I open it just crashes. And no log files I could search to see what the issue could be.

Their website said version 16.04+ and above is supported. So was curious. I also did a check on all the dependencies and the only one missing is "libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0". I don't see it in the repository to install it separately. Not sure if this could be an issue. In one of the forums it mentioned that it's not supported by Ubuntu anymore instead to install "libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev". I installed it separately but still no luck.

Zoom client version being installed: Version 5.10.4 (2845)
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Run this command from terminal and it will work fine ;)

zoom --disable-gpu-sandbox

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Comment: This worked, awesome much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any way to make that setting permanent?

Comment: @Bauna you can change what the desktop icon launches and it's arguments with kmenuedit on KDE or GNOME menu editor. This doesn't change how it launches from URLs though. Hopefully zoom fixes the issue soon.

Comment: I'm doing this and it "works" but the audio keeps cutting out and mouse clicks don't work half the time

Comment: Just installed Zoom 5.10.6 (3192) on Ubuntu. Looks to work better!!

Answer (score 5):

## Upgrade to latest zoom

Latest version of zoom (5.10.6 (3192)) has this problem fixed (for my machine Alienware M15 R4), but some coworkers have reported that "virtual backgrounds" option has been broken on this one. Microphones and webcams USB are not being started ok https://github.com/flathub/us.zoom.Zoom/issues/334 . On more updated versions (as of this writing latest is 5.13.7), this issue is fixed. Download from https://zoom.us/support/down4j or install via snap with

```
sudo snap install zoom-client
```

## If everything fails, call morhook

If your zoom doesn't start altogether you can test if with

```
zoom --disable-gpu-sandbox
```

things get better. Even one more workaround, you can use old zoom version 5.9.6.2225. You can download it from https://cdn.zoom.us/prod/5.9.6.2225/zoom_amd64.deb

## Credits

Enjoy your travels! And hopefully you can get to your meetings on time. Always test your zoom and audio-setup with at least 5 minutes before the meeting.

Comment: Link to download center: https://zoom.us/support/down4j Note that the "Ubuntu Software" / snap version lags a bit behind the releases.

Answer (score 3):

I raised a request with zoom and they acknowledged this bug and then it was released inside 5.10.6.

Comment: It has already been released! Just installed Zoom 5.10.6 (3192) on Ubuntu. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

BLUF: I was experiencing the same problem, but rebooting my workstation solved it for me.

Either clicking on a zoom link, running `zoom`, or running `zoom --disable-gpu-sandbox` would briefly open a window, but it would immediately close. Uninstalling and reinstalling zoom had no effect. Running `su zoom` gave me an error message involving PulseAudio being missing, so on a hunch, I rebooted. Running zoom then opened the crash reporter window, after which I was able to use zoom normally.

Comment: same thing happened to me! Next time it happens check if your nvidia driver is working correctly with command `nvidia-smi` .

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Zoom client on both 18.04 and 20.04 and ran them with different kernels (as an attempt of solving a different problem) and every time it randomly crashed. I've also seen several people complain.

I ended up using the browser to join meetings, it works flawlessly. Maybe try that until they fix the client.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possibly an answer if you also have an internal graphic card:

I have both an Intel internal graphics and a dedicated Nvidia card.
Interestingly I only have the same issue (Zoom crashing on Ubuntu 22.04) when my Nvidia card is enabled (`sudo prime-select nvidia`; command works with proprietary nvidia driver). Zoom works fine with the Intel internal GPU (`sudo prime-select intel`).

So there could be a problem how Ubuntu 22.04 interacts with nvidia drivers (in my case the proprietary nvidia-driver-510).
If you have an integrated GPU, try out Zoom with that.

Comment: Was using KUBUNTU 20.04 and zero issue with Zoom client. Upgraded to 22.10 and now have the very same crash at start up others are describing.
Both on my PC and my wife's laptop (upgraded her system as well) both with nvidia but hers uses a much older driver 390.147 while mine uses 510.60.02 
Neither of us had issues prior so I think it's more to do with Ubuntu OR something other than nvidia ... just my thoughts

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes then it is likely not a problem specific to nvidia 510. I've edited my post to be a little bit more clear.

Comment: @Maligaant Menuk same situation in my case. I regret updating the client now because it was working fine before...

Answer (score 0):

If the answers above do not help, following this steps worked for me!

To enable Disable desktop screen sharing for meetings you host for all users in the account:

1. Sign in to the Zoom web portal as an admin with the privilege to edit account settings.
2. In the navigation panel, click **Account Management** then **Account Settings**.
3. Click the **Meeting** tab.
4. Under In **Meeting (Basic)**, verify that **Disable desktop screen sharing for meetings you host** is enabled.
5. If the setting is disabled, click the toggle to enable it. If a verification dialog box appears, click **Turn On** to verify the change.
6. (Optional) If you want to make this setting mandatory for all users in your account, click the lock icon , and then click **Lock** to confirm the setting.

(source) https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360037710871-Disabling-desktop-screen-sharing-in-meetings